# Simple question about averages

Tags: average

I have got feedback from a survey where the range is 1-10, where:

```
10 = 0 total
9 =  0 total
8 = 0 total
7 = 3 total
6 = 5 total
5 = 2 total
4 = 3 total
3 = 1 total
2 = 0 total
1 = 0 total
```

I would like to work out the average from the range, how can I do this. Thanks

Comment: Just divide the total points by the number of respondents.

Comment: $\frac{21+30+10+12+3}{14}=\frac{76}{14}$?

Comment: Add the total number of points and divide by the number of responses.

Comment: so if 2 people scored 2, will it be 2+2 = 4?

Comment: That's the total number of points, but you still must divide by the number of respondents.  (Note:  it should be clear to you that the average response can not be greater than all the responses.  Also, if every response is $N$ then the average response is surely $N$).

Comment: You should hopefully understand why "The average of $1,3,5,7$ is $\frac{1+3+5+7}{4}$."  For your problem, it might help to instead of thinking of it listed as you had originally to instead think of the problem of finding the average of $7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,5,5,4,4,4,3$.  You do it in the same way as before, by adding each and dividing by the total number of datapoints.  The *only* difference between the two problems is how the information is presented.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u$ be the mean we are looking for. $u$ is found by summing the total number of points by the number of responses.
$$ u = \frac{3(7)+6(5)+5(2)+4(3)+3(1)}{3+5+2+3+1} $$
$$ u = \frac{21+30+10+12+3}{14} $$
$$ u = \frac{61 + 12 + 3 }{14} = \frac{76}{14} $$
$$ u = \frac{34}{7} $$
$$ u \doteq 4.8571429 $$

I hope this helps.
Bob